# Basic log in screen design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, login, visual-design, style

This is the log in screen for our winforms app:

[image: login dialog]

I can't put my finger on it, but I don't like something about the aesthetics of this. Something about it just doesn't seem particularly stylish, or clean, or *usable*.

Is the font is too big? Wrong font? Too many sizes or fonts?
Do the input fields have too little padding?

Is there a standard pattern that I'm feeling in my gut but not delivering on?
What is it about this simple form that just feels wrong?

Comment: *"questions here are expected to be relevant for a variety of people in the same situation"* < I answered this question because I feel it does exactly that. **This is a ubiquitous screen and the OP's example is rife with common errors.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The problem

The Gestalt principles of grouping and similarity are at play here. The form is crowded. Too little space within and between elements creates a block that your brain tries to digest as one, then it finds the important chunks.

### Quick and easy fixes

1. Explanation text is too small.
2. Text needs more space below.
3. Fields need more margin between each other.
4. Fields need more internal padding.
5. Buttons could use some extra space on the top.
6. Visually differentiate "okay" and "cancel" actions.

**Bonus points:** Get your app off Winforms as soon as possible!

### Putting it all together

I question the need to tell them to use their active directory creds. Most users don't want to think about the architecture behind their sign in. I'd go a step further and use field labels rather than introduction text.

This is a very straightforward form that users will complete with ease.

[image: Simple sign in panel wireframe]

Comment: I agree. this should not be locked and this is a thoroughly useful answer for a VERY common problem within UX design. But... sign in should be on the right, not left. Cancel is left. Forward is right ;)

Comment: @Confused I was supporting his Windows-centric world 

Comment: Yeah... Bill. What a human.

Comment: I've had a crack at editing the question to make it more general and use the scenario presented as an example of the problem/question. This really shouldn't be locked, and your answer is very good.